# WinInet FtpOpenFile timeout

Tags: wininet

I have an app that regularly uploads file using WinInet's FTP functions.  It's been running for years but started failing on 4/1/2021.  It fails opening a file using FtpOpenFile with a status of 12002 Internet Timeout.  The call looks like this..

```
    hiOpenFile = FtpOpenFile(
        hiSiteConnect,
        "TEMP.htm",
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII,
        NULL
    );
```

The file does get created on the server.

I'm wondering what the time out value for this function is and if there is anyway to change it?

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting 12002 Internet Timeout with both `FtpOpenFile` and `FtpGetFile` but both work now after adding the `INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE` flag to my `InternetConnect` call.

Regarding timeouts, normally you would use `INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`,`INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT`, or `INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT` with `InternetSetOption`. See here for details on the option flags: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/option-flags

However, due to a very old MS bug, setting the timeout as above simply has no effect whatsoever. There is a workaround to reduce the timeout but not to increase. It is done by creating a new worker thread and waiting for it. See here for the article:
https://mskb.pkisolutions.com/kb/224318